Как сделать структуру статической? C#
Как правильно написать структуру, чтобы поля login и password были статическими, и их значения можно было прочитать из другого класса, обратившись к ним по типу, например ReaderAccountData.login
Компилятор ругается на this - доступ к члену на ссылку через экземпляр невозможен
 public struct ReaderAccountData
  {
      public static string login;
      public static string password;

      public ReaderAccountData(string login, string password)
      {
          this.login = login;
          this.password = password;
      }
  }



Так вы ж сами написали ответ — заменить this.login на ReaderAccountData.login (правда, вы всё равно творите какую-то дичь, но это уже отдельная история)

class вместо struct напишите и конструктор уберите. Но реальная задача хз, которую вы решаете. Вам по идее надо избавляться от статики, а не наоборот.

Поясните (желательно прямо в вопросе) какая семантическая связь между параметром login в конструкторе и статическим полем login (если таковая имеется)? Что должно происходить со статическими полями (их значениями), если создать несколько экземпляров ReaderAccountData с разными параметрами? Для чего, в целом, нужны эти статические поля?
